# Vue Router "push" how to preserve path's query string

Tags: vue.js

**router.js**

```
...
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },

    {
        path: '/x',
        name: 'X',
        component: X
    }
];
...
```

**x.vue**

```
...
mounted() {
    const definedElsewhere = '/?a=b&c=d';

    this.$router.push({ path: definedElsewhere });

    // This seems to work but I don't know how to access "resolve()"
    // inside "beforeRouteEnter()" with "next()".
    // this.$router.push(this.$router.resolve(definedElsewhere));
}
...
```

Good: I'm redirected "Home".

Bad: The query string is not preserved unless I use `query: { a: 'b', c: 'd' }`.

Question: Is there a way to preserve the query string without using `query{}` inside `push()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're dealing with a hardcoded string, you can just pass that into the `push` method as-is.  Check out the first example in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html).

```js
this.$router.push(definedElsewhere);
```